# MacBook Air (Early 2015, El Capitan) Detecting Headphones in Audio Jack When None are Connected

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

Rather than listing the Internal Speakers as an output device, my MBA only shows "Headphones" in "Headphone Port." Restarting the computer did nothing, and resetting the PRAM seemingly did nothing.

Comment: just dirt in the plug. give it good clean

Comment: A 'good clean' does not mean sticking anything metal in the jack, nor using a liquid of any sort, nor alcohol or any other solvent in the jack. Use a toothpick first, then some compressed air-in-a-can. Don't use your own breath as it will be too humid, and if you accidentally force saliva into the jack, that'll be even worse.